# Objective-c : cannot init a class object

Tags: objective-c

I am getting an issue cannot init a class object even after adding lines to the constructor such as

```
self = [super init];
```

or

```
self = [[super init] alloc];
```

And I am not sure what to do.

This is the specific error:

```
file:///%3Cunknown%3E: test failure: -[LinkedListTest testAdd] failed: *** +[NList<0x8e14> init]: cannot init a class object.
```

.m

```
@interface NList()
@property (weak, nonatomic, readwrite) NSObject *head;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger *size;
@end

@implementation NList
@synthesize size = _size;
- (id) init:(NSInteger *)size {
    //is this even necessary? I don't want object methods.. or do I ?
    if (self){
        _head = nil;
        _size = size;
    }
    return self;
}
```

.h

```
@interface NList : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger *size;
@property (weak, readonly, nonatomic) NSObject *head;

- (void)add:(NSObject *)node;

@end
```

test class

```
- (void)testAdd
{
    NList *testList = [[NList init] alloc];
   // Card *testCardOne = [[Card init] alloc];
   // [testList add:(testCardOne)];
    XCTAssertNotNil(testList.head);
}
```

I have tried adding the line

```
    self = [[super init] alloc];
```

to the constructor to no avail.

No visible interfacce for nlist declares

```
or self = [super init]
```

complains cannot init a class object!

## EDIT

I realized that it is not asking me for the size! the constructor requires a size parameter...how do I do this! Ahh [looks up docs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things.

**You need a default constructor**

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.head = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now that you have a default constructor (that calls the superclasses constructor), you need a more specific one for your purposes.

```
- (id)initWithSize:(int)size {
    self = [self init]; // sets head, calls super constructor.
    if (self) {
        self.size = size;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Edit:  Note, the last one had to be in your `.h` file so it is visible.
And also, when instantiating this class, call

`NList *list = [[NList alloc] initWithSize:mySize];`

Comment: Interesting! Why does it need to be declared in the header? That seems unusual? Shouldn't it become public automatically?

Comment: default constructor is not required

Comment: @BryanChen For his purposes, I believe it is. He is doing specific initialization. Thankyou for your feedback, though.

Comment: without default constructor, the code behave the same. (unless `setHead:` is implemented with some custom logic) and I can't see any reason to have it.

Answer (score 3):

You're a little backwards.

How about:

```
NList *testList = [[NList alloc] init:SIZE];
```

where size is the SIZE init you want to use.

Alloc comes before init when you're instantiating Objective-C objects.

Comment: NList *testList = [[NList alloc] init:2];  gives me an error No visible @interface for 'NList' declares the selector 'init:' .. = c

Comment: Did you forget to add "`#import "NList.h"`" to the top of whatever .m file you're using NList in?

Comment: Still getting  No visible @interface for 'NList' declares the selector 'init:' .. yeah I am importing!